# MongoDB projection in Google Apps Script (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-apps-script, mongodb-query, projection

I haven't found a MongoDB driver that I can use in Google Apps Script, so I have to resort to native JavaScript.

I have managed to query a MongoDB with filters using the following lines.

```
const query = { name: { $regex: 'john', $options: 'i' } };
const payload = { filter: query, collection: 'customers', database: 'database', dataSource: 'dataSource' };
const options = { method: 'get', contentType: 'application/json', payload: JSON.stringify(payload), headers: { 'api-key': apiKey } };
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endPoint, option);
```

What I would like is for the query to return only some fields using projection, like this:
`{ name: 1, age: 1 }`
But I cannot get any use out of this.